# How do I listen for changes in a query from another component in react-query?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I want to define a query using the `useQuery` hook in one component and listen to changes in that query from another component.

For example, in a parent component I define a query:

```
const { data, isFetching } = useQuery(["posts"], fetchPosts);
```

And in one of its children I want to listen or subscribe to changes in that query. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom hook for that:

```
import { useQuery } from "@tanstack/react-query";

export default function useObserveQuery<TData = unknown>(queryKey: string[]) {
  return useQuery<TData>(queryKey, { enabled: false });
}
```

Usage:

```
type TPosts = { title: string, body: string }[]; // this is optional
const { data, isFetching, isError } = useObserveQuery(["posts"]);
```

Explanation: the hook accepts a `queryKey` as a parameter and passes it down to the `useQuery` hook. Then, we set the `enabled` option of the `useQuery` hook to `false` to make sure it doesn't throw an error saying that the `queryFn` is missing.

If you need to listen for data changes, you'll most likely also want to have some intellisense, so you can pass a `TData` generic parameter to specify the data type (If you're using JavaScript, ignore this)